# Erro genérico Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Já procurei em todo o fórum e não encontrei um erro que corresponde ao meu. Se alguém puder me ajudar. Estou com este erro:

> Erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um
>   objeto.

```
Linha 1:  @model MimoLacosAdm.Models.CATEGORIA
Linha 2:  @{
Linha 3:      IEnumerable<MimoLacosAdm.Models.listaCategoria> listaCategoria = (IEnumerable<MimoLacosAdm.Models.listaCategoria>)ViewData["listacategoria"];
Linha 4:      
Linha 5:  }
```

Model:

```
namespace MimoLacosAdm.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class CATEGORIA
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public CATEGORIA()
    {
        this.PRODUTO = new HashSet<PRODUTO>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Código")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Categoria deve ser informada")]
    [Display(Name="Categoria")]
    public string NOME_CATEGORIA { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PRODUTO> PRODUTO { get; set; }
}

public class listaCategoria
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string nome_categoria { get; set; }
}
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MimoLacosAdm.Models;

namespace MimoLacosAdm.Controllers
{

public class CategoriaController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Categoria/
    private mimolacosadmEntities db = new mimolacosadmEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Action = string.Empty;
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var categ = db.CATEGORIA.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(0)).FirstOrDefault();
        var lstcategoria = from a in db.CATEGORIA
                           select new listaCategoria
                           {
                               id = a.ID,
                               nome_categoria = a.NOME_CATEGORIA
                           };
        ViewData["listacategoria"] = lstcategoria.ToList();
        return View(categ);

    }
    public List<listaCategoria> CarregaGrid(int? id)
    {

            if (id != null || id > 0)
            {
                return (from a in db.CATEGORIA
                            where a.ID == id
                            select new listaCategoria
                            {
                                id = a.ID,
                                nome_categoria = a.NOME_CATEGORIA
                            }).AsParallel().ToList();

            }
            else
            {
                return (from a in db.CATEGORIA                                
                            select new listaCategoria
                            {
                                id = a.ID,
                                nome_categoria = a.NOME_CATEGORIA
                            }).AsParallel().ToList();
            }
    }
}
}
```

View Index:

```
@model MimoLacosAdm.Models.CATEGORIA
@{
    IEnumerable<MimoLacosAdm.Models.listaCategoria> listaCategoria = (IEnumerable<MimoLacosAdm.Models.listaCategoria>)ViewData["listacategoria"];

}
<p><b>Categorias</b></p>
<hr />
<div id="cadastro">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cadastro</legend>

            <ul style="list-style:none;display:inline-table">
                <li>
                    <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#corposite" href="@Url.Action("Incluir","Categoria")" role="button"><img src="/Contents/Images/btnAdd.png" /></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="btnIncluir" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#corposite" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Categoria", new { id = Model.ID})" role="button"><img src="/Contents/Images/btnExcluir.png" /></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        @{Html.RenderPartial("formCategoria", Model); }
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="Grid">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Lista Categoria</legend>
            @{Html.RenderPartial("listaCategoria", listaCategoria);}       
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

View formCategoria:

```
@model  MimoLacosAdm.Models.CATEGORIA

@using (Ajax.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.Action, "Categoria", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "conteudo-cadastro"
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <ul style="list-style:none;float:left">
        <li>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)</li>
        <li>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.ID)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.ID, new { @readonly="true" })</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="list-style:none;float:left">
        <li>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.NOME_CATEGORIA)</li>
        <li>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.NOME_CATEGORIA)</li>
        <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.NOME_CATEGORIA, new { @size="50px" }</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="list-style:none;float:left;clear:both;display:inline-table">        
        <li><button type="submit" value="Gravar" style="border: none">Gravar</button></li>
        <li><button type="reset" value="Cancelar" style="border:none">Cancelar</button></li>
    </ul>
}
```

View listaCategoria:

```
@model IEnumerable<MimoLacosAdm.Models.listaCategoria>
@{
    IEnumerable<MimoLacosAdm.Models.listaCategoria> listaCategoria = (IEnumerable<MimoLacosAdm.Models.listaCategoria>)ViewData["listacategoria"];
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: listaCategoria.ToList(), canPage: true, ajaxUpdateCallback: "conteudo-cadastro", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "Grid", defaultSort: "nome_categoria", rowsPerPage: 10);
}

@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "grid", alternatingRowStyle: "alternate", headerStyle: "header", columns: new[] {
    grid.Column(columnName: "id", header: "Código",format: a => new HtmlString(Ajax.ActionLink((string)a.id.ToString(),"Detalhe",new { id = a.id },new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "conteudo-cadastro" }).ToString()),canSort: true),
    grid.Column(columnName: "nome_categoria", header: "Nome",format: a => new HtmlString(Ajax.ActionLink((string)a.nome_categoria.ToString(),"Detalhe",new { id = a.id },new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "conteudo-cadastro" }).ToString()),canSort: true)
})
```

Banco de Dados: SQLServer

A Tabela está vazia, pois ainda não tenho registros gravados.

Comment: Bem vindo @Mario, te aconselho a formatar seu código usando a "Amostra de código" para que possamos te ajudar :)

Comment: Tentei formatar, acho que deu certo ... aguardo a ajuda. Obrigado!

Comment: A gente precisa saber em qual linha ocorre o erro.

Comment: O erro ocorre aqui: ViewBag.Action = string.Empty;
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var categ = db.CATEGORIA.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(0)).FirstOrDefault();
        var lstcategoria = from a in db.CATEGORIA
                           select new listaCategoria
                           {
                               id = a.ID,
                               nome_categoria = a.NOME_CATEGORIA
                           };
        ViewData["listacategoria"] = lstcategoria.ToList();
        return View(categ); na chamada da index IEnumerable...

Comment: @MarioAntonioPagnozzi, o erro de null reference acontece por você tentar acessar algum atributo de um objeto nulo. Tente colocar um breakpoint na linha onde você está tendo o problema e ir debugando variável a variável para ver qual está vindo nula. Acho que essa é a única forma até então de te ajudar :)

Answer (score 3):

Esse erro ocorre ao tentar referenciar um membro de um objeto(variável) que está nula.

O método FirstOrDefault pode retornar nulo, enviando um model nulo para a view, no entanto não parece ter sido isto a causa do problema, mas vale testar substituir por um `new Categoria()`

```
var categ = db.CATEGORIA.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(0)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Como você disse, o erro ocorre ao acessar a viewdata, na linha 3 da view(). A chamada RenderPartial não repassa a ViewData, daí o problema

Você pode separar a parte da Action que preênche esta viewdata em outra action e então chamar RenderAction(), ou seja, criar uma action para a view e preencher a viewdata nela.

ou então repassar a viewdata, utilizando uma das técnicas descritas na resposta abaixo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117367/pass-viewdata-to-renderpartial

Comment: Valeu pela sua sugestão, deu certo. no controller criei uma ActionResult para o formulário e um ActionResult para a lista, na view chamei ambas por RenderAction, vou postar a solução.

Answer (score 1):

como o @Davi Fiamenghi sugeriu segue a solução:

Controller ficou assim

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MimoLacosAdm.Models;

namespace MimoLacosAdm.Controllers
{
    public class CategoriaController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Categoria/
        private mimolacosadmEntities db = new mimolacosadmEntities();

        public ActionResult Categoria()
        {
            ViewBag.Action = string.Empty;                        
            return View();

        }
        public ActionResult FormCategoria()
        {            
            return PartialView("formCategoria");
        }
        public ActionResult ListaCategoria()
        {
            ViewData["listacategoria"] = CarregaGrid(null).ToList();
            return PartialView("listaCategoria");
        }
        public List<listaCategoria> CarregaGrid(int? id)
        {

                if (id != null || id > 0)
                {
                    return (from a in db.CATEGORIA
                                where a.ID == id
                                select new listaCategoria
                                {
                                    id = a.ID,
                                    nome_categoria = a.NOME_CATEGORIA
                                }).AsParallel().ToList();

                }
                else
                {
                    return (from a in db.CATEGORIA                                
                                select new listaCategoria
                                {
                                    id = a.ID,
                                    nome_categoria = a.NOME_CATEGORIA
                                }).AsParallel().ToList();

                }

        }

    }
}
```

e a minha View Categoria (Antiga viu Index que troquei para ficar melhor a identificação) ficou assim:

```
<p><b>Categorias</b></p>
<hr />
<div id="cadastro">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cadastro</legend>

            <ul style="list-style:none;display:inline-table">
                <li>
                    <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#corposite" href="@Url.Action("Incluir","Categoria")" role="button"><img src="/Contents/Images/btnAdd.png" /></a>
                </li>                
            </ul>

        @{Html.RenderAction("FormCategoria", "Categoria"); }
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="Grid">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Lista Categoria</legend>
            @{Html.RenderAction("ListaCategoria", "Categoria");}       
    </fieldset>
</div>
```